# "Dave saying that really pissed me off" 2 subjects?

Tags: subjects, grammatical-case, gerund-phrases

So I was teaching and came up with a sentence like this. I'm British and it seems like something I could imagine saying but the grammar seems weird and the students didn't like.

I'm NOT TALKING ABOUT POSSESSIVES BEFORE A GERUND which has been answered here.

Are sentences like this possible? If so what is going here?

1.. Him saying that annoyed me.

2. You doing that caused so many problems.

Comment: You say (shout actualy) "*I'm NOT TALKING ABOUT POSSESSIVES BEFORE A GERUND*", but you actually are.  Both of your examples are grammatically  incorrect:  "Him" and "You" should be "His" and "Your", or "saying that" and "doing that" should have a pair of commas around them.

Comment: Sometimes a sentence can be analyzed by adding the missing bits. Dave, (by) saying that, really pissed me off.

Comment: Both your examples are fine. You can use an accusative personal pronoun or a genitive one. The choice depends mainly on style, with the genitive being characteristic of fairly formal style.

Comment: @tchrist This question is about whether gerund-participial clauses (with their own subjects) can be used as subjects, though.